# Checkout not redirecting to PayPal upon submission of form in IE and Firefox

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I've searched high and low for an answer to my problem, but haven't found one. I'm using the Commerce PayPal EC module to allow users to purchase ads on my site. It works well in Chrome and Safari, but for some reason in IE and Firefox, when the user clicks "Buy Now", they don't get re-directed to PayPal; instead, they just stay on the page with the form. Very frustrating.

The cause of this is not because they've already submitted a form (which should never be a cause anyway, since I want users to be able to submit as many orders as they want). Also, it's not because of the settings of a single computer because I've tried submitting orders in IE and Firefox on multiple computers, and each time clicking "Buy Now" doesn't re-direct me to PayPal. Can anyone tell me what's going on?